# EditorPart with default "..."-button for editing textfield

Tags: web-part, custom, inputformtextbox

I have made a Custom WebPart, with some Custom EditorParts in it.

My Custom EditorPart consists of a simple TextBox and a Validator.

My only problem is that I'd like my TextBox to have that "..." button which default custom property fields have that you can click on and get a popupwindow where you can enter your text.

I have tried InputFormTextBox but haven't been able to customize it to resemble the SharePoint default-behaviour.

I suppose I could roll my own using jQuery but I have a feeling that I could use an existing SharePoint-control to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your webpart project you can add an Application Page which will the user can enter text or whatever you'd like. Then in your web part add:

```
<a style="color: #08184a; text-decoration: underline;" href="" 
            onclick=" javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: '~/_layouts/yourcustomapplicationpagehere.aspx', title: 'My custom popup', height: 500, width: 700 }); return false; ">
```

This will allow you to use the SharePoint Modal Dialog popup.

Comment: Sounds like quite a good solution. Even though I was hoping for a out of the box control which I could use I think I will try this solution and if noone comes with a better solution soon I will accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up adding a CSS-class to my textbox inside the EditorPart. Then I made a jQueryplugin which applied the functionality to all textboxes which have this cssclass. And it worked well.